# Visual Studio C# Watch window and arrays

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, watch

I'm currently investigating some problems with a list (or array, I'm using "list" in this post equally to an array because an array can be converted to a list when needed)

For example I have

```
List<Car> cars = new List<Cars>();
```

My Car object is made this way

```
public class Car
{
    public double Weight {get; set;}
    public double TopSpeed {get; set;}
    public int NumberOfPassengers {get; set;}
    public string ModelName {get; set;}
}
```

In the watch list I want to see the items of the list but only care about the `ModelName` property. Is there any way to show me the expanded list in the watch list and only show the `ModelName` property?

Currently when I expand the list It shows me that it contains 4 elements and in the Value column it only shows me `(somename.namespace.Car)`. So I need to expand every element of the list further to see all properties but this is getting messy if the list gets longer or there are many elements in the list. One constraint --> the class Car is not under my control and therefore I can't overwrite its `ToString()` method or use `[DebuggerDisplay()]`.

I tried using Linq `ForEach(x => Console.write(x.modelName)` but that is not working.

I'm happy about any advice or tip :-)

Comment: Have a look [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/7-ways-to-look-at-the-values-of-variables-while-debugging-in-visual-studio/#7-immediate-window), different window, but it should do the trick for you.

Comment: Could be possible for you to Inherit from `Car` class and crate your own like this `public class MyCar: Car {}` where you can overwrite the `ToString()` method ?

Comment: Yes that's possible. but I'm explicitly searching for a way where I don't have to alter the source code. Because this often requires recompiling and therefore restart of the application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @nilsK hint. I found this solution:
Simply using this watch expression:
`myListWithCars.Select(x => x.modelName).ToList()`

Comment: Hi, @ White. Does this solution solve your problem? If it is solved, you can click ‘✔’ to accept it as an answer. It is helpful for community members to solve the similar problems.

Comment: Hi @hui-liu-mfst yes this solves my problem. I will accept this as an answer as soon as I'm able to do so ;-) Stackoverflow told me yesterday I have to wait 2 days before I can accept this as the answer ;-)